# Problems with Ubuntu 12.04 install on Windows 7 image

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

For work many of our programmers are using ubuntu 12.04 for their systems. All of our computers however are required to run Windoze 7 for our encryptions software.

When Installing ubuntu 12.04 on this image for some reason Grub2 is not installing correctly and after the install the computer goes straight into Windows. I have been able to successfully repair grub by running boot-repair on a live disk but this solution is not suitable for doing on every machine that we build.

Can anyone tell what may be causing Grub to not install correctly? I have tried creating a new image, partitioning the drive manually, partitioning the drive with the installer, downloading older versions of 12.04  nothing seems to change the behavior after install.

Since this is an image it is being installed on multiple types of systems. The 2 that I have tried recently are both dells. One was a M6700 and the other is an E6530.

Boot repair documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Thanks

Comment: Without any hardware information, partition info, (atleast the boot-repair url) we can only guess what is wrong.  Check for uefi installation guide if it is enabled in your systems. Please edit your question & update hardware details, partition info etc.

Comment: Not the boot-repair doc, run boot repair on the affected system and crate a bootinfo summery. it will give you a pastebin url, post that. :)

Comment: Please **don't put the answer inside the question.** You can answer your own question below in space marked for **Your Answer** and then accept it as the correct one by putting a green check mark next to it. Do not put [Solved] in the question title. The green check mark signifies that the question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

There are several windowsprograms (especially 3rd party programs with the word "secure" in it) that tamper with the bootsector and hence, killing GRUB in the process.

Old but still actual refs:

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/ucgi/~cjwatson/blosxom/debian/2010-08-28-windows-applications-making-grub2-unbootable.html

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1447786

Comment: Please give an example and source info if possible. :)

Comment: The software is not installed on the image. That is the last thing that I install on the computer after it is completed. So this couldn't be the issue. Thanks

Comment: @Web-E:    http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/ucgi/~cjwatson/blosxom/debian/2010-08-28-windows-applications-making-grub2-unbootable.html    http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1447786

Comment: That's 3 yr old topic. Anyway thanks for reference. You can add it to your answer. :)

Comment: Yep, 3 yr old... and these practices are still happening. Things tend to go a bit slower in Windows world ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**After looking into this I found that the boot files were not being installed anywhere when trying to install. The solutions to this is as followed.

1. When Installing Ubuntu select "Do something Else" as the install selection
2. Create a partition that is 128mb and at the /boot location
3. Create partition that you want ubuntu to be install on in / location
4. create file partition of swap area.

With the /boot partition Ubuntu then knows where to put grub during installation.**